# SQL: как выбрать запись попадающаю в интервал разных записей в таблице?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Есть база на PostgreSQL 14. В таблице поля `numb`(BIGINT), `id`(Varchar), `date_from`(TIMESTAMP)
В ней записи такого вида:

```
numb;id;date_from;
124455;5820;2022-07-20 08:01:29; 
124455;5820;2022-07-24 08:01:29;    
124455;5402;2022-07-27 00:01:31;
124455;1020;2022-07-28 00:06:01;
```

У нас есть дата (в условии) '2022-07-26 21:03:23', нужно построить запрос так, чтобы за один запрос выбрать предыдущую запись у которой `numb` = 124455 и `date_from` была бы меньше чем в записи с  '2022-07-27 00:01:31'

В результате мы должны выбрать только запись: '**124455;5820;2022-07-24 08:01:29;**', так как дата у нее больше чем дата следующей по времени записи: '2022-07-27 00:01:31' и больше у записи с датой '2022-07-20 08:01:29'.

Т.е получается мы всегда должны выбирать только одну и только предыдущую запись от той, у которой `date_from` меньше чем '2022-07-26 21:03:23', но не больше чем следующая запись с `date_from` '2022-07-27 00:01:31'.

Comment: Один запрос выбирает соседа ДО, второй соседа ПОСЛЕ. Ну и обычный себе UNION.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос

```
select * from test
where date_from=(select max(date_from) 
          from test where date_from<cast('2022-07-26 21:03:23' as datetime)
       )
```

[Пример](https://dbfiddle.uk/Sq-UbF8s)

Если нужны записи с конкретным numb, Ваш пример нужно переделать так

```
select * from test
where (numb = 124455) 
  AND date_from=(select max(date_from) 
          from test where date_from<cast('2022-07-26 21:03:23' as datetime) 
                     AND (numb = 124455)
       )
```

Comment: А если у нас будут еще записи с другими `numb` где время будет например совпадать, а нам нужен только `numb` = 124455 ? Попробовал добавить условие по numb - результат он выбирает и другие записи тоже. Пример: https://dbfiddle.uk/5wAWw6xd